# JavaScript selector for data-event?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to select an element based on the data-event attribute?

Here is what I have:

`<button data-event="5456293788" class="id-button-yes greenBtn  list-buy-buttons">Buy now!</button>`

Looking for something like:

`document.getElementByDataEvent('5456293788')`

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
document.querySelector("button[data-event='5456293788']");
```

See in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MpHms/)

It has quite a wide [browser support](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) (even IE 8 supports it)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [attribute selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector)

http://jsfiddle.net/QTNzf/

**JS**

```
document.querySelector('button[data-event="5456293788"]' );
```

**CSS**

```
button[data-devent="5456293788"] {
      background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged "javascript", not "CSS".

Comment: @FelixKling No I don't, they can use the same query in `document.querySelector`

Comment: Yes of course, but maybe they don't know about `querySelector`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) in jQuery:

```
$('[data-event="5456293788"]')
```

or with [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-event="5456293788"]');
```

For backwards compatibility, you'd have to iterate through all the elements checking the attribute values. This is a case where a library such as jQuery really helps.

backwards compatible raw js:

```
function getElementsByAttr(attr, val) {
    var nodes,
        node,
        i,
        ret;
    val = '' + val;
    nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    ret = [];
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
        node = nodes[i];
        if (node.getAttribute(attr) === val) {
            ret.push(node);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
de = getElementsByAttr('data-event', '5456293788');
```

Comment: @Snuffleupagus, i wasn't done, I hadn't meant to post it when i did

Comment: @M.Woodard, do you have any other selector library available, or is there a particular reason that you can't add jQuery/Prototype/Sizzle/something else?

Comment: yeah, cannot add a library, it is not my site ... I am running a macro script against a site so it must be strictly js

Comment: @M.Woodard, and what do you think `var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js';
s.onload=function() {
    alert('loaded');
};
document.body.appendChild(s);` will do?

Answer (score 1):

The [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) does spring to mind, and you don't need jQuery to use that.
It probably won't work on older browsers, though.

If you really want, you can add a `getElementsByDataEvent` to the `document` object (not sure if all browsers allow this):

```
document.getElementsByDataEvent = function(dataEvent)
{
    return document.querySelectorAll('[data-event="'+dataEvent+'"]');
};
```

But as you can see, this is a bit unnecessary, since it's just returning the return-value of a `querySelectorAll` call. What's more, if you use `querySelectorAll` directly, you can do something like this

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[data-event="foo"]');//only links will be retured
//or, with some other data-* thing, along the lines of:
document.querySelectorAll('[class="greenBtn"]');
```

Comment: you would need to do this by doing this `document.prototype.getElementsByDataEvent = function()`.

Comment: @ryan: No, because `document.prototype` is undefined. You don't have to change the prototype to add a new property to an object, so why would you need to do so here?